# I want to Show another Cell on the Selection of "Other" Cell in TableView using Swift 4.2 to 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let tblContent = tblViewCustomFields[indexPath.row]

    let title = tblContent
    let custmCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCellForLetKnowUs

    let customTextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell") as! CustomTextCell

    custmCell.lblInfo.text = title
    if indexPath.row == 7 {
        //            cellList.append(.withTxtFld)
        //            tableView.reloadData()
        customTextCell.textView.isHidden = true
    }

    return custmCell

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly explain the requirement in detail.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show different cell on certain row ?

Comment: please read this article to get overview of how to use tableview. 
https://medium.com/@andycherkashyn/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ios-uitableview-79b766bf1a42

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if indexPath.row == 7 { 
          let customTextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell") as! CustomTextCell
          customTextCell.textView.isHidden = true
          return customTextCell
     }


     let custmCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCellForLetKnowUs
     custmCell.lblInfo.text = tblViewCustomFields[indexPath.row] ?? ""

     return custmCell
}
```